# Detect (or register) dot as comma in textbox using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform created using Excel VBA, where the user enters some data and then saves it to a worksheet using a button. Some of the fields the user needs to fill are only supposed to have numeric values. In order to only allow numbers in those textboxes I use the following code:

```
Private Sub txtShift1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Debug.Print KeyAscii
  If KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57 Then
    Debug.Print "number"
  Else
    Debug.Print "other"
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

However, there is one more adjustment I would like to make. The user usually fills those fields using a numeric keypad, which has a dot as decimal separator. In my region, the comma is used as decimal separator, and I am unable to change that configuration on every computer that will be used. So, I am looking for a piece of code that registers the dot character as a comma when typing in a specific text field. Something like what the Windows 10 calculator does. If you have commas as decimal separators and type the dot in the numeric keypad while using it, you get a comma instead of a dot to easily do calculations.

I suppose this could be achieved using the same `KeyAscii` property, but I could not figure it out. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
  Debug.Print KeyAscii
  If (KeyAscii >= 48 And KeyAscii <= 57) Then
    Debug.Print "number"
  ElseIf KeyAscii = 44 Then
    Debug.Print "comma"
    If Application.DecimalSeparator = "." Then
        Debug.Print "switching to period..."
        KeyAscii = 46
    End If
  ElseIf KeyAscii = 46 Then
    Debug.Print "period"
    If Application.DecimalSeparator = "," Then
        Debug.Print "switching to comma..."
        KeyAscii = 44
    End If
  Else
    Debug.Print "other"
    KeyAscii = 0
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This works perfectly! Thank you very much for your help Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Application.DecimalSeparator = ","`

Comment: I believe Application.DecimalSeparator is only relevant if the user doesn't have the UseSystemSeparators option checked.

Comment: @Kevin Oeda: In a way... But `Application.UseSystemSeparators` default value is `True`. If you changed it, anyhow, it is a read/write property and you can change it back (in VBA code), in order to serve your scope. And finally switch it back, if you really do not need it to be `True`.

Comment: That could work. I will try that and see if it works. Thank you for your help!